# Анимация с альфа каналом во Flash

Tags: анимация, flash

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажете, как программно реализовать анимацию с альфа каналом? Допустим, чтобы человечек передвигался по фону во flash. Единственный способ, который приходит в голову, - это сделать кучу картинок png и заменять их по таймеру. Есть ли другие способы анимации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- c Flash CS3 есть анимация на основе костей (bones), векторные формы гнуться на ура
- можно сделать анимашку из битмаповых кусочков человека, (стопы, голень, бедро, торс ...)
- с 8 версии флеша, есть поддержка кодеков с альфа каналом, то есть рендерим в сторонней проге (3ds max, AfterEffect), во флешке только двигаем видео кусок

Comment: Спасибо. А можно по подробнее о 3ем варианте? В какой формат нужно рендерить? И нет ли возможности сделать это в anime studio или в самом флэше?

Comment: - делал несжатый AVI или секвенцию PNG c альфаканалом, затем импортировал в Flash CS, если нужен чистый FLV/F4V, то в Adobe Media Encoder
 - конечно анимацию можно сделать внутри Flash CS, тогда никуда импортировать не нужно, использовать как MovieClip
 - про anime studio ничего не скажу, нужно чтобы оно экспортировало кадры или видео с прозрачным фоном (альфа каналом)